# JavaFX fx:include scene visibility of parent controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

As far as I can gather from the rather lacking [JavaFXML documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements), fx:include is a way in which one can separate FXML into individual files and then include them into another just as if the files' contents were copy-pasted: i.e. similar to using a C include compiler directive.

However, it would appear this is not the case as the nodes within the included FXML document are not visible to the parents' controller. Consider the following:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="Sample.controller">
    <ToolBar xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:id="aToolbar">
        <Button fx:id="aButton" text="Press me Baby!"/>
    </ToolBar>
</GridPane>
```

Which works as expected but the following code does not...

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="Sample.controller">
    <fx:include source="children.fxml"/>
</GridPane>
```

Where *children.fxml* contains the following (like above):

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<ToolBar xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:id="aToolbar">
    <Button fx:id="aButton" text="Press me Baby!"/>
</ToolBar>
```

Here the nodes within *children.fxml* are not visible to the parent controller despite the fact the nodes within children.fxml  become part of the scene graph who's root has a controller.
The result (if one was to attach an event handler to aButton) is a *NullPointerException*.

So... Do FXML files included using *fx:include* require their own controller and if so, why? It would be a nice feature to separate large portions of the scene graph without requiring communication between multiple controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the included FXML files are separate FXML files, and so they should have their own controller class. This makes the included portion reusable, without any reference to the including FXML file's controller, and means you can change the included FXML file without having to worry about where it may be included, and what other code you may be breaking. In other words, the included FXML-controller pair is fully encapsulated in its own right.

The documentation [explicitly shows how to communicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) between the controllers in this case.